# How to get certain keys from the array of objects and put them in state?

Tags: reactjs

I am training to do requests to server with json.placeholder. The result of request is the array of objects with many keys.
For example the array of objects

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  },
and so on ...
```

But I don't need all these keys. Only to take some of them, for example name, username and id and put it in my State.
How to do that properly?

Comment: Hi Ivan, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use map. 
Using map I choose keys that I need, creating new objects. Then I put this array in my state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

```
response = [ { "id": 1, "name": "Leanne Graham", ...}, {...}, ...]
cleanResponse = response.map(user => return {name: user.name, contact: user.email})
```

Here, with `.map` we return an object that has two property : `name` and `contact`.
We set name to `user.name` and contact to `user.email`

## Anwser

I don't know much about ReactJS, but your anwser only require basic javascript :

### [Array.Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

You can use `.map` on an array to convert its elements :

```
nameArray= [ "George", "Alice", "Portevent" ]

presentationArray = nameArray.map(name => "My name is " + name)
// presentationArray  = [ "My name is George", "My name is Alice", "My name is Portevent" ]
```

`nameArray.map` will iterate on each element. `name` will be equal to "George", then "Alice" etc...

Foreach element, it will be replaced with `"My name is " + name` (remember, name will have each different value).

**Note : .map doesn't change the initial array, it just create another array** (so we save it inside presentationArray

A more advanced use of map :

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]

function tenToPower(n) {
    return 10 ** n
}

numbers.map(number => tenToPower) // [10, 100, 1000]

numbers.map(number => {
   if (number < 3) return "Failed"
   else return "Valid"
}) // ["Failed", "Failed", "Valid"]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
         const item = data.map((user) => {
             if(user.username === 'Bret'){
                  setName(user.name);
                  setUserName(user.username);
                  setId(user.id)
             }
         })
```